# ssas 2005 deploy project and process options

Tags: ssas

I have seen many articles but still feel confused about different process options on different objects (dimension, cubes).

In my sample project, there was initially one measure group: Sales. Three dimensions: Date, Product, Branch. I got these deployed and no problem.
Then I added a new measure group to the cube: Sales 1. Sales will 'join' with existing Date and Branch and a new dimension: Code.

When I was processing the cube using process default, I thought it should process newly added measure group (Sales 1) and dimension (Code) only, but why I saw it's also processing existing Sales measure group?

And what's the difference between processing the cube and deploy the project? My understanding is process the project will automatically process the cubes and/or dimensions. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, deploying just updates the definition, i. e. structure of your database, while processing just loads the data. But deploying also always does an unprocess of those objects that structurally changed and those that depend on them, as the data would not match the new structure. Note that e. g. making an object visible or invisible, or in many cases renaming an object is not considered a structural change, but adding or removing a sub object like an attribute or measure is considered a structural change.

And then, there is BIDS trying to make things simple by trying to automatically do things that you did not explicitly trigger: In the default setting, after a deploy, BIDS issues a "Process default" command. You can configure if this should be done or not if you right-click on the project node in Solution Explorer in BIDS, select Properties and then Configuration Properties/Deployment/Processing Options. I tend to keep the default setting for small cubes, and set it to "DO not process" for larger cubes that would take some time to process. But then, I have to be aware that the cube may not contain all data if I did some deployments recently without processing.

And for why your first measure group was processed, maybe you did a small structural change to it without realizing.